# Git automatic merge through branches

Tags: git, merge, githooks

I am trying to implement a hook that automatically merges through some branches that we currently have.

Let's say we have 4 branches: `project-1.0`, `project-1.1`, `project-1.2`, `master`.

The goal is, that if we have to fix an issue at some at let's say `project-1.0` that change to automatically propagate to the rest of the branches.

I was reading https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/git-automatic-merges-with-server-side-hooks-for-the-win, which seems like a good start, however is there a better way to accomplish something like that?

Since the `update` server side hook, is executed once a pusher is trying to update. Since it's called before anything is updated, wouldn't that merge the previous commit and *NOT* the actual?

Comment: Have you seen the [python script](https://bitbucket.org/nicolapaolucci/automatic-merge-hook/src/6165f597fcc5c52218e4d720422807678e2e3337/update?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) referenced in the blog article? If so: What further improvements would you like to get asking for a "better way"?

Comment: @lucash I did see it, but in my opinion the update server side hook will merge the *previous commit* and not the *actual* one, as it's executed before anything is updated. So switching to project-1.1 and merging with project-1.0 wouldn't merge the previous change. Correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: You are right, the hook seems to be doing it the way you say. There are two options to work around that: Either you can use a post-receive hook. This however gets a list of updated references from STDIN, so it will require a bigger refactoring. Otherwise you could make sure the new revision after the update is used for the first merge. I have done this in a [fork](https://bitbucket.org/lucasheuvelmann/automatic-merge-hook) of the repository. This has the downside of a message "Merge commit 'SHA-1' into X.X" (instead of "Merge branch 'refs/heads/X.Y' into X.X") for the merge commit.

Comment: Thanks @lucash, can you add that a a comment, so I can accept it as an answer? Thanks